# To read Email via POP3 using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, pop3

I want to read the Email by giving username and password via POP3 using iPhone SDK for iPhone 4.0. Whether its possible to do it. If not can any body give me any link or open source to do achieve this functionality.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without using a complete POP3 library (and I'm not aware of any that exist for iPhone).  There's nothing in the SDK that will give you this for free.

Comment: On the other hand, POP3 is pretty trivial to implement. Now, if it were IMAP, that'd be another story!

Comment: What is NOT trivial to implement is the MIME parsers used to display any/all kinds of email that actually come in to the user.  This is not an answer to the question.  More just something I have found out when trying to do it myself.